# Java - Swing setting colour to text in JTextArea

Tags: java, string, swing, colors

I have a JTextArea which has its text set to a string of information. In this string of information I have a variable which I would like coloured red, to do this I edit the string as follows:

```
"Result: <html><font color=red>" + negativeValue + "</font></html>"
```

I would expect this to give Result: ## where the number is red. However it just puts the following into the text area:

```
Result: <html><font color=red>##</font></html>
```

I'm not really sure how to get this working, so could someone offer advice as to how to do so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JTextArea` is not a component designed for styled text.  If the text can be all one color, call [`setForeground(Color)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setForeground%28java.awt.Color%29).

Otherwise use a styled text component such as a [`JEditorPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html) or [`JTextPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html).  For more info. on using them, see [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html).

Also as pointed out by others, the entire `String` must start with `<html>` .

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, JTextArea is for plain text display only. For HTML, you must use JEditorPane or one of its subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use HTML in a `JTextArea`, but you can use it with a `JEditorPane`

Answer (score 1):

JTextArea doesn't support styled text area, in order to render HTML you need an instance of JEditorPane or JTextPane. See the [tutorial on Using Text Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)
.

Sample code [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/HtmlDemoProject/src/components/HtmlDemo.java)

Answer (score 0):

Java renders html code only if it starts with `<html>`. You should try it like

```
"<html>Result: <font color=red>" + negativeValue + "</font></html>"
```

Comment: ..and only if it is put into a styled text component.  ;)